# how to hide a facebook post with javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm making a filter for facebook posts. i need to hide all posts which contain some "X" word.

what i need now is a way to hide the post which contain that word. i know how to find the words, i just don't know how to hide that part of the site.

i found some solution with jquery, but i don't want to load entire jquery just for a little action.

Comment: jQuery is 29KB minified and is likely to be in the browser cache if you source it from the Google CDN location. Why is this not an option?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery *would* make this very simple, however using pure javascript:

```
var posts = document.getElementsByClassName("uiStreamMessage");

for(var i=0; i<posts.length; i++){
if(posts[i].innerHTML.indexOf("school") != -1){ posts[i].parentNode.removeChild(posts[i]) };
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does...I just tested it.